# Change internal links with regex or..?

Tags: html, regex, hyperlink

I have links to cold fusion extension pages, such as:

/hsl/incs/10/header.cfm

that simply need to be:

/hsl/incs/10/header.html

I only want the internal links changed, so that if there is a link like this:
http://somesite.com/usescoldfusiontoo.cfm

I dont want that changed. So, I thought of doing reg ex, but find through research that might not be the best way...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to make an `.htaccess` rule? Either way, I think you're looking for `(?!/[^\/]*\.)(cfm)` (http://regexr.com?2tnnr) possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(hsl/.*)\.cfm$ /$1.html [NC,L,R=301]
```

This is assuming you are **internally redirecting** every `/hsl/*.cfm` to `/hsl/*.html`

Comment: I wonder if I asked the question wrong... I think so. What I actually need is:Someone comes to our site via a link:
oursite.com/hsl/coldfusion.cfm... 
they should go to oursite.com/hsl/coldfusion.html  with a 301 status. I want this to happen even if there is a coldfusion.cfm file on the server. 
The above did not work as page:
http://sitedomain/hsl/reference/elec/InternetRes.cfm did not redirect to http://sitedomain/hsl/reference/elec/InternetRes.html; instead it returned a 404 error.

Comment: Alright as per your comments I edited my answer. Please try now.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I ran a simple test, and it appears mod_rewrite is enabled, but not working. So, I have to wait for our sys-admin to come back- thanks!